# Why is it "kiom strange" instead of "kiel strange"?

Tags: word-usage

Or *kiom ofte* instead of *kiel ofte*, etc...

I came across this structure while reading - *kiom* + adverb.

I thought it was odd since to me it sounds like *kiom strange* would mean *how much strange*. Likewise *kiom ofte* seems like it means *how much often*, which sounds odd.

So, why is it not ***kiel*** strange and ***kiel*** ofte?

Is it incorrect to say *kiel* instead?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/grado_kvanto.html):

> La tabelvortoj *kiel* kaj *tiel* montras ne nur manieron, sed ankaŭ gradon. Oni uzu ilin en la samaj lokoj, kie oni povus uzi tre:
>
> - *Vi estas tiel bela, tiel bona kaj tiel honesta, ke mi devas fari al vi donacon.* FE.15 Oni povas diri: *tre bela*, *tre bona* kaj *tre honesta*.
> - *Mi estas tiel forta, kiel vi.* FE.10 Eblas diri: *tre forta*.

So *kiel/tiel* are used when the things referred to are *grades* of something.

And then for *kiom/tiom*:

> La tabelvortoj *kiom* kaj *tiom* montras kvanton. Oni uzu ilin tie, kie oni povus uzi multe:
>
> - *Mi volas tiom da terpomoj, kiom mi povas porti.* Oni povas diri: *volas multe* kaj *povas porti multe*.
> - *Ŝi tiom laboris, ke ŝi fariĝis ĉefo de la firmao.* Oni povas diri: *multe laboris*.

So *kiom/tiom* are used when the things referred to are *quantities* of something.

Then it goes on and links to something called [“Tiom-kiom-ismo”](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/tabelvortoj_om.html#i-8tg) (excerpt):

> *Kiom* kaj *tiom* estas iafoje uzataj pri grado anstataŭ *kiel* kaj *tiel*, kiam oni volas tre forte emfazi. Sed iuj Esperantistoj uzas sisteme nur *kiom* kaj *tiom* anstataŭ *kiel* kaj *tiel* por montri gradon, kvazaŭ ili ĉiam emfazus…

Having all that in mind, let me examine your examples:

- ***strange*** is clearly measured as a *grade*, not *quantity*. So, technically, the proper word should be *kiel/tiel* but as visible from PMEG, one can use *kiom/tiom* for empazis, or because of overuse.
- ***ofte*** to me is a *quantity* (as in how many times something happens in a given time span) but you are free to argue with me about that. So in my opinion the use of *kiom/tiom* here is fine.

Comment: I want to make a more general question about when to use tiom or tiel with adjectives/adverbs, to which this would be a good answer. Would that be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro I think that would be a good question. For example it would be nice to have an explanation of what to use with verbs etc (eg, _via ĉemizo tiel blankas kiel neĝo_)

Answer (score 12):

*Kiel ofte* and *kiel strange* are the normal way of saying *how often* and *how strange*, either in questions or exclamations of surprise. The practical and easy parts in the rules of [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kvantaj_vortoj/grado_kvanto.html) are:

- Oni uzu [la vortojn *kiel* kaj *tiel*] en la samaj lokoj, kie oni povus uzi *tre*
- Oni uzu [la vortojn *kiom* kaj *tiom*] tie, kie oni povus uzi *multe*

It is clear that you can say both *tre ofte* and *tre strange*, so *kiel ofte* and *kiel strange* are perfectly good wordings. There is no need to analyze whether we are talking about grades or amounts (quantities).

There are people (the "*tiom-kiom-ismo*", see PMEG) who don't understand the flexibility of "kiel" and object to its use for anything else than "in which way".

You can say *kiom strange*, but there is strong emphasis in it, something like "what a huge amount of strangeness".

Comment: Tiukaze... kiom strange ĉiam estas, kiam oni ĉiam diras kiom strange!