# Using "tiel" and "tiom" before adjectives, adverbs and verbs

Tags: verbs, correlatives, adjectives, adverbs

Should I use *tiel* or *tiom* before an adjective, adverb or verb?

> Vi estas **tiom/tiel** afabla.
>
> Helpi min estis **tiom/tiel** afable de vi.
>
> Vi **tiom/tiel** afablas.

In English, people say "so" in this context.

Comment: Thsi question is realted to a question asked by Chris McDowell. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/why-is-it-kiom-strange-instead-of-kiel-strange

Answer (score 2):

*Tiom* can be seen as a kind of shorthand for *tiel multe*:

– *Dankon, vi estas* tiel *afabla.* (Thank you, you are so kind.)

– *Ĉu ŝi estis tiel afabla kiel vi atendis?* (Was she so kind as you expected?)

– *Nu, eble ne tiom.* (Well, perhaps not that much.)

In other words, whenever quantity is not in the foreground, the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

In the examples you give, you'd usually say *tiel*. If you say *tiom* it suggests a greater degree.